# How to reject incoming calls using InCallService

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a question :

How i can to **reject** incoming call using **InCallService** .

In the documentation it asks me to use **InCallService** instead of **EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER** in **TelephonyManager**
and instead of **endCall()** in **TelecomManager** because are deprecated
but i don't know about how to use it

This means that the solution to the two questions is from **InCallService**

just, I need to use **reject** call phone in my app , not create default call phone app.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".CallerNumberReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**Class CallerNumberReceiver**

```
package com.example.myapplication1;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyCallback;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

public class CallerNumberReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {

            telephonyManager.registerTelephonyCallback(context.getMainExecutor(), new CallStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state) {
                    if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                        // WHERE IS PHONE NUMBER?
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            telephonyManager.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) {
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, phoneNumber);
                    if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "number : " + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    abstract static class CallStateListener extends TelephonyCallback implements TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state) {

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For, your first question to reject the incoming call you can use the `InCallService`.

```
public class CallService extends InCallService{
    @Override
    public void onCallAdded(Call call){
       super.onCallAdded(call);
       call.disconnect();
    }
}
```

For, your second qustion you can use the method called `registerTelephonyCallback()` To register the `TelephonyCallback` and then override the `onCallStateChanged()` method. For this you need to target API level 31 or above.

Comment: In the second question , I want to get the phone number while phone is ringing .

Comment: Sorry, man I am not completely sure about it.